# Numeric Validation Doesn't Bind Observable (IE10 only)

Tags: knockout.js, numeric

I have problem with IE10. I'm using knockout.js as MVVM. I'm also using input validations to ensure that only numeric values will be accepted. One of the validation is jquery.numeric from [here](http://www.texotela.co.uk/js/plugins/jquery.numeric.js) . Everything works fine in all browsers but not in IE10. Using IE10 the validation is working but the binding is not working  meaning I cannot get the value entered from a textbox it's always empty. Please help here's my code.

**HTML and jQuery**

```
<div class='liveExample'>   
    <p>With jquery.numeric: <input data-bind='value: withnumeric' id="withnumeric"/></p> 
    <p>With/Out jquery.numeric: <input data-bind='value: withoutnumeric' /></p> 
   <p><button data-bind="click: CompareBehavior" type="button">Submit</button>
 </div>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#withnumeric').numeric();
    //this one doesn't work also
// $("#withnumeric").bind("keyup paste",  function () {
//    setTimeout(jQuery.proxy(function () {
//        this.val(this.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
//    }, $(this)), 0);
//});
});
```

**ViewModel**

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.withnumeric = ko.observable();
    this.withoutnumeric = ko.observable();

self.CompareBehavior = function () {
    alert(this.withnumeric());
    alert(this.withoutnumeric());
};
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

If you want to play my jsfiddle just see here http://jsfiddle.net/Vs8yn/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a compatibility issue with Internet Explorer 10 and jQuery-numeric. The good news is that you can tell Knockout to use other events (in addition to `change`) to update the binding. In this case adding `blur` is sufficient:

```
<input data-bind='value: withnumeric, valueUpdate: "blur"' id="withnumeric"/>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vs8yn/12/

Answer (score 0):

In your jsFiddle, you're not binding your view model on load:

```
$(function(){
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
    $('#withnumeric').numeric();
});
```

You also need to initialise the observables with a value:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.withnumeric = ko.observable(0);
    self.withoutnumeric = ko.observable(0);

self.CompareBehavior = function () {
    alert(self.withnumeric());
    alert(self.withoutnumeric());
};
```

I've updated it, and it seems to work in IE10.

Comment: You can ignore the return self; line in the view model, I was just trying a few things first.